# Appearance of drying hemoglobin-and-salt droplets

Tags: crystallography

I initially posted these or similar images at the bio site because they looked to me like organic/mold contamination in a slide (low power) containing hemoglobin and salt. As the slide dried these fibers emerged and joined into arches on the drying edge, eventually forming thorn-like nests draped with heme-containing debris and sometimes NaCl crystals. A seemingly astute commenter there suggested it was "cracks," and the speed at which these things grew made me reconsider. Now I think they are inorganic and caused by dessication--but not cracks exactly. More like a condensation of the protein and salt into forms that resemble hyphae. I saw basically the same with lysozyme and salt. Does anyone have experience with these structures and an idea of what they are?

The top image is shortly before disintegration due to drying out. The bottom is of the initial fiber-like arches that appear near the periphery of the slide. Power is 150x, the colors are as seen, the red material draped over the thorns in the top image are I think just heme-containing debris.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strictly a guess--I think they are tunnels that form in the liquid as entropy forces a rearrangement due to loss of water; cylindrical cracks, as it were.